# Creating ORM-independent POCO classes

Tags: c#, orm, poco

My goal is to create the poco classes without knowing which ORM is going to be used.

Now observe the following code...

```
public class NeuralModel
{
    public NeuralModel()
    {
        Configurations = new HashSet<NeuralModelConfiguration>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastTrained { get; set; }
    //Navigation properties
    public ICollection<NeuralModelConfiguration> Configurations { get; set; }
    //NotMapped properties
    [NotMapped]
    public NeuralModelConfiguration DefaultConfiguration { get { return Configurations.SingleOrDefault(config => config.IsDefault); } }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsTrained { get { return LastTrained.HasValue; } }
}

public class NeuralModelConfiguration
{
    public NeuralModelConfiguration()
    {
        KeyValues = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> KeyValues
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    //Navigation properties
    public NeuralModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose if I were to use **Entity Framework Core**, I get into the issue of mapping complex types (in my example it would be `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`).

According to my research I came across two possible solutions:

1. Serialization
2. Another Entity

Now my question is that is there a third solution that do not require me to change my poco classes but rather do some sort of hidden processing at the dbcontext level?

Should there not be a third solution then out of the 2 available solutions which one would be considered better in terms of performance?

Comment: `ICollection` is the most generic interface, it's not EF-specific. EF Code first puts configuration in the context anyway, so the classes *are* agnostic. What is the *actual* problem? I seriously doubt there's a `KeyValues` table in your database though. Are you trying to create a "dynamic" EAV model? That's a very smelly antipattern

Comment: An ICollection is not really a Complex Type - it can only be mapped directly onto another Entity. Blob serialization is an option but you will have to plug the code in somewhere, in this case I would implement that in the POCO.

Comment: EF 6 and Core work with DataAnnottations so there's nothing specific there that others ORM don't use. Also, think really hard whether you'll ever change ORM before committing into hard work

Comment: If you want to store *neural network* parameters like weights and slopes, the EAV pattern is particularly bad - each parameter has a very different meaning, type and validation. 15.7 is meaningless as a number of levels after all. If you want to store complex *value* objects, ie objects that are handled/retrieved as a whole, a very good option is to store them as JSON and serialize/deserialize it as needed. Many databases, eg SQL Server 2016, Postgresql, allow parsing of JSON too, so if you want to retrieve all experiments with 5 layers, it's still possible

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your feedback. I have read and understood your message. It looks like I'm over complicating things for myself.